# vlc doesn't work after `sudo snap install vlc`

Tags: snap, vlc

When installing via snap, vlc doesn't start. If I try from the commandline I get the following error.

```
$ vlc
VLC media player 3.0.11 Vetinari (revision 3.0.11-0-gdc0c5ced72)
[000055762720bb40] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object weight does not accept value [40 200)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply faulty VLC version by:

```
sudo snap remove vlc
```

and install deb-package with

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

and use it instead.

Comment: Actually just the last line (`sudo apt-get install vlc
`) worked too. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this **fontconfig warning** myself and it seems this problem can happen with any Snap.
The solution in my case were the following lines:

`sudo rm /var/cache/fontconfig/*
rm ~/.cache/fontconfig/*
fc-cache -r`

Execute these lines one by one. The third line can take some time so be patient. Then run your snap again.

I've tested this on Kubuntu.

Source: https://github.com/keshavbhatt/olivia/issues/95#issuecomment-774747492

Comment: Fixed it for me on Ubuntu 23.04

Answer (score 0):

I hit similar issue in Ubuntu 22.04 but the flatpack version seems to work fine (alternative to above apt install)
https://linuxhint.com/install-vlc-media-player-ubuntu22-04/